# Getting DragHandle error with react-beautiful-dnd

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, formik

I'm using react-beautiful-dnd version 8.0.5 (latest) and trying to render a reorganizable list, but I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for 
built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but 
got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file 
it's defined in. Check the render method of `DragHandle`.
```

I've copied part of the code from [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/k260nyxq9v). I currently use react-redux, Formik's HOC and react-virtualized-select. When I copy the code to a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/5x2rkx47jk), it at least renders (glitched, I guess). Does anyone have any idea? I can provide more code if needed.

Comment: What react version are you using in your project ?

Comment: @Pintouch 15.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

react-beautiful-dnd V8.0.5 as a peer dependency to React 16 [check their package.json](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/package.json)

*This explains why it's rendering in the sandbox (React 16), and it's not working on your project (React 15).*

You should have warnings when you execute `npm install`:

You can update React 15 to React 16 or downgrade the version of react-beautiful-dnd finding the last one that works with React 15.

Comment: You're right. It worked. Thank you so much! Just to be saved, the last version of react-beautiful-dnd which works with React 15 is *6.0.2*.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem and went through this solution.  I found that you also have to upgrade `react-dom` as well as `react`.  My current versions for both are `16.4.2`.